# Elasticsearch ignores my JVM heap size settings

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, jvm-arguments

I am running Elasticsearch inside a Docker container in Linux (Ubuntu). I am having a lot of `circuit_breaking_exception` problems, citing a 486.3mb limit; so I've decided to raise my JVM heap size a bit. My machine has 6 GB physical memory, so up to 3 GB should be safe for the heap size.

So I've gone to change the setting in `jvm.options`. The default is:

```
-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g
```

And I've changed it to:

```
-Xms2g 
-Xmx2g
```

And here comes the twist: not only I keep getting the same `circuit_breaking_exception` with the same size limit; `echo $ES_JAVA_OPTS` returns `-Xmx512m -Xms512m`. This is not even the default setting. I've also tried leaving the default `jvm.options` and creating a new `user.options` inside `jvm.options.d`, with the same result. Am I missing something? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Hi, can you add how you are running elasticsearch as in if you can share the Dockerfile if you are building your own image or using the official image. For the official image I am able to pass `- "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"` as the environment variable and able to increase heap size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in the [official installation of ES using docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html), you can pass it as env variable

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es01
    environment: -> it comes under environment section, removed other settings for brevity
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" --> note this
```

**You need to restart the docker container after changing this `ES_JAVA_OPTS` env variable value**

Comment: Aww, it looks like I was doing just this. I'm modifying my `docker-compose.yml` and see what happens. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: @Gorpik glad you found it useful, please don'r forget to upvote and accept the answer :D

Comment: I was just checking that it worked, and it did. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with `-XX:-MaxFDLimit` or `-XX:+MaxFDLimit` instead of heap size and it isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass this setting to container using env var `ES_JAVA_OPTS`.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
```

Comment: This would create a new container, wouldn't it? I'd like to modifiy the current one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, in a docker environment, you have to set it in the docker-compose.yml

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file